# Creating unique dataframe from all csv files stored in different folders

Tags: python, pandas

I have several folder which stores several csv files. I would like to create one unique file/dataframe using a function in Python.

A folder, called `Main_Folder`, has 3 subfolders: `Folder from A`, `Folder from B`, `Folder from C`.
Folder `A` contains three csv files:

- filename1+key;
- filename2+board;
- filename3+cat;

Similarly the other two folders, `B`

- filename1+tast;
- filename2+board_1;
- filename3+dog;

and `C`

- filename+test;
- filename+b;
- filename+d;

What I have tried is

```
def create_dataframe(nam):
    path = "path/Folder from "+nam+"/"
    files = [f.split('.')[0] for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]

    dataframe={}
    for file in files:
         dataframe[file] = pd.read_csv(path+file+'.csv')
```

but it seems not working (no output when I call the function). I think my approach is wrong.
My desired output would be a dataframe (unique) having all files from the different three folders (A,B, and C), with two extra columns, one for A/B and C (i.e. which can tell me the dataset where it comes from) and another one for the filename.

Something like this:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 .... Source  FileName
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..       A    filename1+tast
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..      ..    ..
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..       A    filename3+cat
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..       B    filename1+tast
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..      ..    ..
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..       B    filename3+dog
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..       C    filename+test
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..      ..    ..
.. .. .. .. .. .. ..       C    filename+d
```

Please let me know if you need more details or if you have any questions on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is not working, because it does not return anything.

To combine different dataframes you can use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) method.

For example:

```py
def create_dataframe(paths):
    """ Creates combined dataframe from csv files in paths """

    def get_files_in_path(path):
        return [f.split('.')[0] for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]

    dataframes = {
        (path, file): pd.read_csv(path + file + '.csv')
        for path in paths
        for file in get_files_in_path(path)
    }

    df = pd.concat(dataframes, names=['path', 'file', '_'])
    return df

paths = [f"path/Folder from {name}/" for name in ['A', 'B', 'C']]
df = create_dataframe(paths)
```

You can also call `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` to convert index into columns:

Comment: thank you ZTEP. Where should I put inform on paths (A,B, C) and files (i.e. all the csv files in those folders). Since I will have many files stored there, I would prefer to do this automatically rather than manually

Comment: hi, @Val, I updated code to use one function to load all data from paths

Comment: Thank you ZTEP. Unfortunately am getting this error: NameError: name 'path' is not defined. The error is here: `----> 4     files = [f.split('.')[0] for f in listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]`

Comment: Yes, my mistake, I incorrectly updated the list of files

Comment: Thank you so much @ZTEP